# Como carregar dados do banco para a view welcome no laravel?

Tags: mysql, php-7, laravel-5.3

Estou criando um sistema no laravel 5.3, já activei o auth e meti um carousel na view welcome que busca o endereço das imagens no banco. Quando acesso a rota padrão da view welcome, dá o erro de «o método não existe». Criei um controller, acessei a mesma view numa rota com este controller, dá outro erro. Aqui vai o código para melhor perpçao:

**View welcome**

```html
@extends('portal.template')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-home" data-ride="carousel">


            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                @foreach($postCarousel as $postCar)
                    {{--<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{{$i}}"></li>--}}
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' :'' }}"></li>
                @endforeach
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                @foreach($postCarousel as $item)
                    <div class="item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
                        <img src="{{$item->imagem}}" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgba(133,178,0,0.7)">
                            <p><h3>{{$item->titulo}}</h3></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                @endforeach

            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($postsSite as $key =>$value)

                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4">

                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="{{$value->imagem}}" alt="{{$value->titulo}}">
                        <div class="noticia-titulo-home" >
                            <p class="titVisualizado"><b>{{$value->titulo}}</b></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="noticia-conteudo-home">
                            <p class="contVisualizado">{{$value->descricao}}</p>
                        </div>


                        <div class="caption" style="height: 20px; padding: 5px" >
                            <p>
                                <a href="{{url('visualizar-noticia/'.$value->id)}}" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Ler Mais</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="caption" style="height: 25px; padding: 5px" >
                            <p>
                                {{--<span class="pull-right" style="color: #e38d13">{{$value->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</span>--}}
                                <span class="pull-right" style="color: #e38d13">{{$value->created_at}}</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach


            <p>
                <a style="width: 99%; font-size: 14pt" href="{{url('index-noticia')}}" class="btn btn-success" role="button">VER MAIS NOTÍCIAS <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i></a>
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
@endsection
```

**Controller**

```
public function getPostsCarousel() 
{
    return Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
}

public function getPostsSite() 
{
    return Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(6)->get();
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', function (){

return view('portal.welcome')
    ->with('postCarousel', $this->getPostsCarousel())
    ->with('postsSite', $this->getPostsSite());
```

});

**Erro**

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method getPostsCarousel does not exist.
```

**SiteController**

```
 public function index()
{
    return view('portal.welcome', [
        'postCarousel' => $this->getPostsCarousel(),
        'postsSite' => $this->getPostsSite()
    ]);
}
```

**Route com controller**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'portal'], function (){
Route::get('/','Portal\SiteController@index');
```

});

**Outro erro**

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Comment: Depois de 2 semanas ninguém me ajuda? Pessoal, por favor, preciso muito da vossa ajuda com a questão acima.

Answer (score 0):

consegui solucionar o problema, comentando o bloco abaixo que se encontra no **SiteController:**

**public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('auth');
  }**